# How to create unit test of a transfer of values?

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to perform a test case for a method of transferring between accounts, but it is giving error:

```
@Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        origin = new Account();
        origin.setBalance(50);

        destiny = new Account();
        destiny.setBalance(0);

@Test
    public void transferring_test() throws Exception {
      
        Assertions.assertTrue(origin.getTransferring(),destiny,50);
        Assertions.assertEquals(0, origin.getBalance());
        Assertions.assertEquals(50,destiny.getBalance());
    }
```

**It is accusing error here:**
*Assertions.assertTrue(origin.getTransferring(),destiny,50);*

I want assertEquals methods to check if the source account amount has been debited and the target account amount has been credited.

```
public void transferring(Account destiny, double value) {

        accountRepository.valueBalance(value);
        destiny.setDeposit(value);
    }
```

Comment: What is the error?  Where is the call to perform the transfer? We'll need more details (code) to help.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you aren't calling the `transferring` method correctly. There's nothing to assert on it - you should just call it, and then assert the states of the two accounts:

```
@Test
public void transferring_test() throws Exception {
    origin.transferring(destiny, 50); // Here!
    Assertions.assertEquals(0, origin.getBalance());
    Assertions.assertEquals(50, destiny.getBalance());
}
```

Comment: I ended up not mentioning it, but I call the service. It worked here, thank you very much!